# Window Authentication in dot net core and Angular 6 with JWT token

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

Hi i am looking to make window authentication work using angular 6,.net core 2.1 as back end and JWT token.None of the solutions have pointed towards use of JWT along with window authentication.

Following is code snippet for startup.cs to enable jwt

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                 {
                     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                     {
                         ValidateIssuer = true,
                         ValidateAudience = true,
                         ValidateLifetime = true,
                         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                         ValidIssuer = "EveryOne.Security.Bearer",
                         ValidAudience = "EveryOne.Security.Bearer",
                         ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                         IssuerSigningKey = JwtSecurityKey.Create(Configuration["SecretKey:SecretKey"])
                     };

                     options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                     {
                         OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                         {
                             Console.WriteLine("OnAuthenticationFailed: " + context.Exception.Message);
                             return Task.CompletedTask;
                         },
                         OnTokenValidated = context =>
                         {
                             Console.WriteLine("OnTokenValidated: " + context.SecurityToken);
                             return Task.CompletedTask;
                         }
                     };
                 });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Bearer",
                    policy => policy.RequireClaim("MembershipId"));

            });
```

The user Controller.cs

[HttpPost("AuthenticateUser/")]

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateUser([FromBody]LoginDto user)
{}
```

The angular component call:-

Login(userName: string, password: string): Observable {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.actionUrl + global.ApiMethod.AuthenticateUser, { userName: userName, password: password, grantType: "password" })

The call from angular goes through interceptor -:

```
  import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpSentEvent, HttpHeaderResponse, HttpProgressEvent, HttpUserEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/login/authenticate/authenticate.service';
import _uniq from 'lodash-es/uniq';


@Injectable()

export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor, OnDestroy {

  // public count401: number;
  // public cachedRequests: HttpRequest<any>[];
  // private $refreshToken: Subscription;

  constructor(private authenticateService: AuthenticationService) { }

  // intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  //   // request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('withCredentials', 'true') });
  //   request = request.clone({ withCredentials: true });

  //   // console.log("request with interceptor with http" + request.url);
  //   return next.handle(request);
  // }


  public $refreshToken;
  public cachedRequests: Array<HttpRequest<any>> = [];
  public isTokenRefresh: boolean = false;
  public timer: any;
  public count401: number = 0;

  addToken(req: HttpRequest<any>, token: string): HttpRequest<any> {
    let request = req.clone({ withCredentials: true });
    request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) })
    return request;
  }
  public collectFailedRequest(request): void {
    this.cachedRequests.push(request);
  }
  public retryFailedRequests(token): void {
    this.count401 = 0;
    const uniqCachedRequests = _uniq(this.cachedRequests);
    // retry the requests. this method can
    // be called after the token is refreshed 
    uniqCachedRequests.forEach(request => {
       request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });
      //??What to do here
    });
    this.cachedRequests = [];
  }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any> | HttpEvent<any>> {

    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    const token = currentUser != null ? currentUser.token : "";

    if (this.count401 >= 1 && !req.url.includes('AuthenticateUser')) {
      this.count401++;
      this.collectFailedRequest(req);
      next.handle(req).subscribe().unsubscribe();
    }

    return next.handle(this.addToken(req, token)).pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // do stuff with response if you want
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        // do error handling here
        switch (err.status) {
          case 401:
            this.count401++;
            this.collectFailedRequest(req)
            if (this.count401 === 1) {
              this.$refreshToken = this.authenticateService.refreshToken(currentUser).subscribe(result => {
                if (!result) {
                  this.count401 = 0;
                  this.authenticateService.logout();
                }
                else {
                  const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
                  this.retryFailedRequests(currentUser.token);
                }
              }, error => {
                if (error.status === 404) {
                  this.count401 = 0;
                  this.authenticateService.logout();
                }
              });
            }
            return this.$refreshToken;
        }

      }
    }));

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {`enter code here`
     this.$refreshToken.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you share some code we can look at?

Comment: Why JWT-Token? You can just use cookie-authentication by using `withCredentials: true` within the headers of your angular request. Please checkout those posts if you still persist on having jwt and windows-atuh https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x

https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2

Comment: Updated the question with snippet